# NGINGX gives 502 Bad Gateway when trying to use NGINX + Gunicorn on Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I'm developing a Django app with a PostgreSQL database and I'm using NGINX + Gunicorn with Docker.

PostgreSQL, NGINX and Gunicorn are on different containers communicating with networks. I can build my app with `docker-compose build` but when I execute it with `docker-compose up` and view my app in the browser all I get is a `502 Bad Gateway` error and in the terminal all I see is this:

```
nginx_1   | 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2018:01:53:01 +0000] "GET /home HTTP/1.0" 502 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "172.23.0.1"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [20/May/2018:01:53:01 +0000] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 502 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
```

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database container
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      - db_network

  # Web app container with gunicorn
  webapp:
    build: .
    env_file: ./.env

    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/webapp/src
      - static:/opt/services/webapp/static
      - media:/opt/services/webapp/media
    networks:
      - db_network
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - db

  # NGINX (Reverse proxy) container
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static:/opt/services/webapp/static
      - media:/opt/services/webapp/media
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - webapp

networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_volume:
  static:
  media:
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
# Start with an official Python image
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/webapp/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/webapp/src

# Install dependencies
ADD requirements.txt /opt/services/webapp/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /opt/services/webapp/src

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", "myapp", "myapp.wsgi:application"]
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
bcrypt==3.1.4
cffi==1.11.5
Django==2.0.4
Pillow==5.1.0
psycopg2==2.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
pycparser==2.18
pytz==2018.4
six==1.11.0
django-phonenumber-field==2.0.0
gunicorn==19.8.1
gevent==1.3.1
```

And my NGINX configuration:

```
# Upstream server
upstream myapp_server {
    server webapp:8000;
}

# Main server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/services/webapp/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /opt/services/webapp/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about what could be causing this problem but it looks like gunicorn is not properly detecting my app, NGINX is working and PostgreSQL seems to be working too!

Comment: I am having a similar problem have you got the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need use proxy_pass to your upstream.

```
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://myapp_server;
        break;
    }
```